# Java Swing: can I join checkbox captions into one line?

Tags: java, swing

I would like to ask if how can I achieve this thing. I wanted to add a multiple values in one column in database from checking the check boxes. e.g., if i check three check boxes all the checkbox selected will add in column in database. I have attached the image below for visualization. thank you!

[image: UI Checkboxes and database column subject]

Comment: Use a button group. Then, you can get the value of all the checked buttons in the button group. Once you have that, send the results to the database -- https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api//java.desktop/javax/swing/ButtonGroup.html

Comment: Can I have some example code of it sir?

Comment: Sure, I will submit it as an answer. Of course, I will not be able to simulate your database, because I don't know your database setup.

Comment: I only need the string output sir, I can integrate it to my database since I only know the structure of it. just a bunch of code showing in String format.

Comment: Ok. I have submitted the solution. Let me know if there is information that you need.

Answer (score 1):

I finally got it by exploring and getting some ideas from David.
this is the so much lesser code for it.

```
String subject = "";
    if (cb1.isSelected()) {
        subject = subject + "Subject 1";
    }
    if (cb2.isSelected()) {
        subject = subject + ", Subject 2";
    }
    if (cb3.isSelected()) {
        subject = subject + ", Subject 3";
    }
    System.out.println(subject);
```

Answer (score 0):

I take it back, there's an even easier way that doesn't require ButtonGroup. Simply use an ActionListener.

```java
import javax.swing.AbstractButton;
import javax.swing.ButtonGroup;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JCheckBox;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class SOQ_20220425
{

   public static void main(String[] args)
   {
   
      final JFrame frame = new JFrame();
   
      frame.setTitle("Button Group Example");
      frame.setSize(500, 500);
      frame.setLocation(500, 200);
      frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
      
      final JPanel panel = new JPanel();
      
      final AbstractButton button1 = new JCheckBox("Button 1");
      final AbstractButton button2 = new JCheckBox("Button 2");
      final AbstractButton button3 = new JCheckBox("Button 3");
      
      final AbstractButton check = new JButton("CHECK");
      check.addActionListener(event -> System.out.println("button 1 is selected? = " + button1.isSelected()));
      check.addActionListener(event -> System.out.println("button 2 is selected? = " + button2.isSelected()));
      check.addActionListener(event -> System.out.println("button 3 is selected? = " + button3.isSelected()));
      
      panel.add(button1);
      panel.add(button2);
      panel.add(button3);
      
      panel.add(check);
      
      frame.add(panel);
      
      frame.setVisible(true);
   
   }

}
```

As you can see, check the boxes, then click CHECK. If the checkboxes are checked, the terminal will reflect that.

If you want different behaviour, just change what you do in the ActionListener. In this case, you could have just 1 ActionListener (instead of 3) which figures out if the checkboxes are set, then sends that String to your database. That should solve your problem.

**EDIT** -- added another example.

```
import javax.swing.AbstractButton;
import javax.swing.ButtonGroup;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JCheckBox;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class SOQ_20220425
{

   public static void main(String[] args)
   {
   
      final JFrame frame = new JFrame();
   
      frame.setTitle("Button Group Example");
      frame.setSize(500, 500);
      frame.setLocation(500, 200);
      frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
      
      final JPanel panel = new JPanel();
      
      final AbstractButton button1 = new JCheckBox("Button 1");
      final AbstractButton button2 = new JCheckBox("Button 2");
      final AbstractButton button3 = new JCheckBox("Button 3");
      
      final AbstractButton check = new JButton("CHECK");
      check.addActionListener(event -> printButtonString(button1, button2, button3));
      
      panel.add(button1);
      panel.add(button2);
      panel.add(button3);
      
      panel.add(check);
      
      frame.add(panel);
      
      frame.setVisible(true);
   
   }
   
   private static void printButtonString(AbstractButton... buttons)
   {
   
      String output = "";
   
      for (AbstractButton button : buttons)
      {
         
         if (button.isSelected())
         {
            
            output += button.getText() + ", ";
            
         }
         
      }
      
      output = output.length() == 0 ? "" : output.substring(0, output.length() - 2);
      
      System.out.println(output);
   
   }

}
```

Comment: It doesn't work. it only outputs boolean. TRUE and FALSE

Comment: Then make a map, with a key of string, and a value of boolean. Then, turn the map into a string, and send that

Comment: example daw kol

Comment: Done. I have even made this one simpler, so no map required.

Comment: thank you so much for your effort Sir, but none of this helps me and Finally I got the right thing to do in exploring. I used only this bunch of codes.

Comment: I'm glad it worked out

Comment: I answered my question above Sir, see how the code works.

Comment: I see it now. Looks good